# Javascript using fetch to POST multiple BODY types

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I am trying to use a fetch to POST data to a remote server that will run a PHP script. When I try the fetch with just the formData, it works. However, when I add the API as a second post variable into the POST, it throws an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0`. I am thinking since the API is not actually formdata, am I not allowed to append it as formdata? Also, are we able to POST two types in the BODY, let's say formdata and text?

```
function exeCtCoreAPI(api) {
    var url = "executetest.php";
    console.log ("this is the URL: " + url); // this is correct
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('gateway', gatewayName);  
    formData.append('api', api);    
    console.log ("these are the post data: " + api + " " + gatewayName); //these are correct
    fetch(url,
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        //do something with the json
        console.log("This is the returned params: " + JSON.stringify(json));
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}


exeCtCoreAPI("myAPI");
```

It seems to throw the error before it hits the php script, cause when I dump the POST in the PHP I don't see anything echoed out.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: what your `api` variable look like ?

Comment: The issue most likely comes due to your `handleErrors` helper. What does it return and why is it executed before `response.json()`?

Comment: @DominikJanković The handlingError helper is fine, cause without the `formData.append('api', api) ` data and just the gateway, it works fine. Only after i added the api it breaks..

Comment: @Ayoub my api variable is just a php file like this `GetData.php`.